# SQL Server Agent is not ending some jobs correctly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, sql-server-2019

we observed a strange behaviour after migrating our datawarehouse from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2019. Our Agent runs most of the jobs correctly after the migration. However there are a few were the single steps are getting marked as successful but the overall job is still marked as running. The job itself is also not getting restarted again based on our schedule. So the job is caught in that status. Of course we can try to build up a new agent job for the affected ones but would be interesting to know if someone had similar experience or knows were this behaviour is coming from.

We have currently SQL Server 2019 Enterprise Edition CU1 running. Agent XPs are set to 1.

Any clue what this is causing?

Comment: If you check https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2019?tab=Newest, you'll see that there are now 3 SQL Agent issues reported on the first page.  The others are different from yours, but there's no way anybody but Microsoft can fix something like this that just isn't working right.  Open an incident with Microsoft is my recommendation.

Comment: @TonyHinkle...good advice...will do..we already rolled back from CU2 to CU1 to solve these issues. Which worked by the way. The agent is now running much more stable. However the above issue is still there and I wanted to check if this behaviour is observed by someone else...especially straight after a migration...

Comment: Looks like there are some fixes for Agent in CU3 released 3/12.